# Vue chartjs is not rendering from API

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js

I have an API that gives me data about certain things. With that data, I would like to render my chart dynamically. However, when I use that API in the `created()` segment, it does not get rendered. But if I shift my data to hardcode it in the `data()` segment, it works. May I seek advice here?

```
 export default {
        extends: Line,
        data() {
            return {
                lineChartOptions: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero: true }, gridLines: { display: true } }], xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false } }] },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                    },
                },
                lineChartData: [],
            };
        },
        created() {
            axios
                .get("someurl")
                .then((response) => {
                    let responseData = response.data;
                    let lineDataset = [];
    
                    for (let i = 0; i < responseData.pidList.length; i++) {
                        lineDataset.push({
                            label: responseData.pidList[i],
                            backgroundColor: "#2554FF",
                            data: 2000,
                        });
                    }
    
                    console.log(lineDataset);
    
                    this.lineChartData = { labels: ["2020", "2021"], datasets: { lineDataset } };
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        mounted() {
            this.renderChart(this.lineChartData, this.lineChartOptions);
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vue-chartjs does not live update by default, this is because chart.js does not support it. To make it live update you will need to add the `reactiveProp` mixin as described in the documentation: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts